# How to have Visual Studio Code recognize text inside ' ' (backticks) as code?

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, styled-components

[image: Sample code snippet in Visual Studio]

The text inside of `` is not recognized as CSS.

I would like VS Code to not color it as normal ASCII text and treat it as CSS code, noting mistakes in spelling, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go. Just install this extension:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=styled-components.vscode-styled-components

Comment: I came here looking for a VScode plugin that would recognize HTML in backticks in .js files. If you are looking for such a plugin then js-in-string will do the job.